# How do I shorten a datetime (YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS) to year-month (YYYY-MM) in a dataframe (python/pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[Example_Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nXdn.png)

I'm trying to fill in the ? fields...

I've been trying to do: 
test_df['date'] = test_df['datetime'][:10]

However I'm getting no luck... thank you!

Comment: What specifically does "shorten" mean? Are these actual date/time objects which you want to convert to strings? Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: See my answer, happy to assist further if you need more understanding. You are on the right track. As I said, time series are special, take tutorials and understand them. Once understood they are powerful.

Comment: could you provide the *code* itself, instead the screenshot? and the link to the screenshot is even worst. By doing that, everyone could benefit from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datetime series are special.They are very powerful if you understand how to manipulate them.

Avoid splitting/slicing datetimes, they are adequately catered for in python.

I would do the following

Generate sample data
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
np.random.seed(0)
# create an array of 5 dates starting at '2015-02-24', one per minute
rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=5, freq='T')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': rng, 'Val': np.random.randn(len(rng)) })
df
```

[image]

Extract Year Month

```
df['month']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

`pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`- Coerces Date to datetime

`[dt.strftime('%Y-%m')]]`-returns specified Date string format

Output

[image]

Comment: Can you please press the upward button on the left. That  will add me a point

Answer (score 0):

The [`.str` attribute](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#string-methods) is required to handle text data:

```
test_df['date'] = test_df['datetime'].str[:7]
```

This will give you just the year and month from the datetime column